# dhcp3-server or isc-dhcp-server

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp

So. I need a dhcp server on my ubuntu server.
I've found two options, and some saying it's the same thing?

Could someone explain the difference, maybe even pros and cons? If it's not the same.

Comment: What is the two option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package *dhcp3-server* was renamed some time ago to *isc-dhcp-server*.

```
apt-cache search dhcp.-server
isc-dhcp-server - ISC DHCP server for automatic IP address assignment
dhcp3-server - ISC DHCP server (transitional package)
...
```

Installing either *dhcp3-server* or  *isc-dhcp-server* will have the same result.

```
apt-case show dhcp3-server |grep ^Depends
Depends: isc-dhcp-server
```

Comment: Any differences in editing it's options?
As in, file in /etc/init.d or any config file named differently?

Comment: dhcp3-server has no own content, it is a meta package.
A difference in the name of config files occurs (/etc/dhcp3 --> /etc/dhcp), but this are like migrating a major version of a package (e.g. squid --> squid3).